# Android Simple Cursor deprecated and class loader

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I'm trying to read in data stored in SQLite. I was following a tutorial which used Simple Cursor Adapter to read in the data, however I find now that this is deprecated. I've read about Class loaders but the documentation indicates that its suitable for API 11 and above. My target level API is 7? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Code below just in case its required.

```
public class MyCourses extends ListActivity {

    static final String TEST = "com.example.mycoursetimetable.TEST";
    String [] MODULE;
    EditText EditCode, EditName;

    private database MODULEDATABASE;  
    ListView listContent;

    SimpleCursorAdpater cursorAdpater;
    Cursor cursor;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



       listContent =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
       MODULEDATABASE = new database(this);

       cursor = MODULEDATABASE.getData();
       String [] from = new String[]{database.KEY_MODULECODE,database.KEY_MODULENAME};
       int[] to = new int[] {R.id.labelModuleCode,  R.id.labelEditModuleFull};

       cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listcourses,cursor,from,to);
       listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);


        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem, you can still use `Loaders` from `android.support.v4` package. The APIs look and work the same as on API >= 11, so any tutorial designed for genuine `Loader` classes will work for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CursorLoader from the support package, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/CursorLoader.html .  Here's a good example that talks about both http://responsiveandroid.com/2012/03/19/using-an-android-cursor-loader-with-a-content-provider.html